# Deseo crear una tabla con control de asistencias en mysql con una consulta(query) esto es para mostrar en una web hecho con html y php

Tags: php, mysql, date

Muchas gracias a todos, me gustaria compartir mi consulta, he desarrollado una practica donde se quiere hacer una tabla con horas de entrada para trabajar en lenguaje php, pero como no domino php, quiero hacer la consulta hacerlo por mí

Base de datos (id int - nombre varchar - fecha date - hora time)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi consulta es

```
**$consulta = "select id, nombre,
(SELECT hora where DAYOFWEEK(fecha)=2 )as lunes,
(SELECT hora where DAYOFWEEK(fecha)=3 )as martes,
(SELECT hora where DAYOFWEEK(fecha)=4 )as miercoles,
(SELECT hora where DAYOFWEEK(fecha)=5 )as jueves,
(SELECT hora where DAYOFWEEK(fecha)=6 )as viernes,
(SELECT hora where DAYOFWEEK(fecha)=7 )as sabado
 from asistencia";**
```

MI resultado es
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas agrupar por nombre y aplicar una función de totales a cada grupo. Yo he utilizado `MIN()`, pero igual prefieres `MAX()` o `AVG()` para detectar los días llega más tarde, o la hora a la que, en media, suele llegar, respectivamente:

```
SELECT nombre,
  MIN(if(DAYOFWEEK(fecha)=2,hora,NULL)) L,
  MIN(if(DAYOFWEEK(fecha)=3,hora,NULL)) M,
  MIN(if(DAYOFWEEK(fecha)=4,hora,NULL)) X,
  MIN(if(DAYOFWEEK(fecha)=5,hora,NULL)) J,
  MIN(if(DAYOFWEEK(fecha)=6,hora,NULL)) V,
  MIN(if(DAYOFWEEK(fecha)=7,hora,NULL)) S,
  MIN(if(DAYOFWEEK(fecha)=1,hora,NULL)) D
  FROM asistencia
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY id;
```

Para este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE asistencia(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(31),
  fecha date,
  hora time
  );
INSERT INTO asistencia (nombre, fecha, hora) VALUES
  ('Luis',  '2022-07-04',   '08:42:09'),
  ('Mario', '2022-07-04',   '08:20:09'),
  ('Jose',  '2022-07-04',   '08:50:09'),
  ('Luis',  '2022-07-05',   '08:00:09'),
  ('Jose',  '2022-07-05',   '09:00:09'),
  ('Luis',  '2022-07-06',   '08:25:09'),
  ('Mario', '2022-07-06',   '08:45:09'),
  ('Jose',  '2022-07-06',   '08:10:09'),
  ('Luis',  '2022-07-07',   '08:00:09'),
  ('Fahmix','2022-07-07',   '08:39:09');
```

Se obtendría:

```
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+------+
| nombre | L        | M        | X        | J        | V    | S    | D    |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+------+
| Luis   | 08:42:09 | 08:00:09 | 08:25:09 | 08:00:09 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| Mario  | 08:20:09 | NULL     | 08:45:09 | NULL     | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| Jose   | 08:50:09 | 09:00:09 | 08:10:09 | NULL     | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| Fahmix | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | 08:39:09 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Muchas gracias es exactamente lo que buscaba, te agradezco infinitamente , lo estoy aplicando a mi php y me quedo tal y como lo deseaba. 
Bendiciones desde Perú.